# Java: read from console until getting a blank line

Tags: java

I wrote this method, which is never ending. It isn't printing what I'm passing, why?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {

   public void readFromConsole() {

          ArrayList<String> wholeInput= new ArrayList <String>();  

          InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

           try {
                String line = null;
                while (!(line = br.readLine()).equals(" ")){
                wholeInput.add(line);
           }

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       for (int i =0; i<wholeInput.size();i++){
              System.out.println(wholeInput.get(i));
       }
    }
```

}

Comment: believe readLine() will also pull in the carriage return, since the method is simple I'll try testing this out with a compiled file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`" "` is not an empty line, it is a space. Try `""`

```
while (!(line = br.readLine()).trim().equals("")){
```

Comment: yup it worked if you put a blank space in... also I retract my previous statement about the carriage return, should have checked the docs, my java is rusty sorry: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Comment: Notice I also put a `trim()` in there