# BufferedReader.readLine() waits for input from console

Tags: java, console, bufferedreader, readline, lines

I am trying to read lines of text from the console. The number of lines is not known in advance. The BufferedReader.readLine() method reads a line but after the last line it waits for input from the console. What should be done in order to avoid this?

Please see the code snippet below:

```
    public static String[] getLinesFromConsole() {
    String strLine = "";
    try {
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            strLine += line + "~"; //edited

        isr.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strLine.split("~");
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the code never exits the while loop. And correctly so. An idea would be that when you read something specific, like "exit", you could break.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) strLine += **line** + "~";`?

Comment: you should use some condition to exit the while loop, for example having the user type exit

Comment: You appear to be skipping every second line, which I suspect is not correct and you are waiting for the end of the input stream which is difficult for most console users to type. ;)

Comment: I try your code when you invoke readline second time while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            strLine += //here br.readLine() + "~"; console start to wait another character; you should use line variable   OldCurmudgeon suggest this solution. And you can determine a exit command.

Comment: Corrected the skipping line part. It was a typo.
strLine += **line** + "~";

Comment: Is it possible to to end the readLine() execution without having an exit string?

Comment: This is duplicate question. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506778/java-read-from-console-until-getting-a-blank-line

Answer (score 4):

The below code might fix, replace text `exit` with your requirement specific string

```
  public static String[] getLinesFromConsole() {
    String strLine = "";
    try {
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("exit") )
            strLine += br.readLine() + "~";

        isr.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strLine.split("~");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to to end the readLine execution without having an exit string?

Comment: to rerminate the text input process , you need some 'text' to indicate quit or exit.

Answer (score 1):

When reading from the console, you need to define a "terminating" input since the console (unlike a file) doesn't ever "end" (it continues to run even after your program terminates).

There are several solutions to your problem:

1. Put the input in a file and use IO redirection: `java ... < input-file`

   The shell will hook up your process with the input file and you will get an EOF.
2. Type the EOF-character for your console. On Linux and Mac, it's <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, on Windows, it's <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Stop when you read an empty line. That way, the user can simply type <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

PS: there is a bug in your code. If you call `readLine()` twice, it will skip every second line.