# reading both stdin and arguments from command line java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble reading both arguments and stdin from the command line when running a java file. I can read in arguments on their own and stdin on it's own but not together; for example:

```
java myFile 6 2 < numbers.txt
```

I can get it to store 6 and 2 in an array but then it just stores "<" and "text.txt" also. I've been unable to find anything online describing a similar problem so not really sure where to begin.

Comment: Adding your code might be extremely helpful here

Comment: The `> file.txt` mantra is more Unix style, and I'm not sure that Java would support that (since all of the arguments from `args[]` make it into `main()`).  Have you tried writing out to a file in Java instead?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using '<' for input redirection?

Comment: @blackcompe:  For Unix/Linux, `<` reads information into a file, and `>` reads the output of a running script and writes it to a sufficient output pipe.  If you want to write out to a file, use `>`.  But, that's a script, not Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command-line arguments are received in the `String[]`-typed parameter of the `main` method. Input redirection is done the same as for any other process invoked at the command line. The bytes can be retrieved by reading from `stdin` until `EOF` is reached.

Command: `java myClass myArg < myFile`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Arg 1 = " + args[0] + "\nStdin = ");
    try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in)) {
        int ch;
        while((ch = isr.read()) != -1)
            System.out.print((char)ch);
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For more info:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

Comment: Perfect! Could you describe how the code knows the difference between the arguments and the stdin?

Comment: brilliant thanks, so if I were to read a string file (opposed to integer in this instance) into an array I would have to change the relevant ints to Strings and place the array insertion line instead of the print line.

Comment: @user2152251: You're talking to code specific without code in your post. What is a string file? All cmd-line arguments are treated as strings. Post a code example or else I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: I think I could have been clearer in the original post. I'm simply trying to read the contents of the < text.txt file into a string array, so I initially needed help with actually being able to read the file that came under the < input.txt (which your post solved). I was able to read typical arguments but wasn't sure how to read through stdin.

Comment: @user2152251: If you want to read the lines of the redirected input (i.e. the file), you can wrap the `InputStreamReader` in a `BufferedReader` and store each line from `BufferedReader.readLine` into a String array element. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581205/bufferedreader-readline-waits-for-input-from-console

Comment: I just found that out reading some inputreader documents! Works great thanks.